# Правила расстановки знаков препинания в сложносочиненных предложениях

Tags: пунктуация

По какому принципу расставляются знаки препинания в СПП, если его части представляют собой номинативные предложения (?), а последняя часть - безличное предложение (?) - по принципу соединения однородных членов? Или последняя часть - отдельное предложение?

20 лет начала деятельности, 10 лет производства газового оборудования и произведен пятитысячный ШРП.

Comment: Совет - не начинайте предложения с цифр.  Или добавьте слово или прописью "двадцать".

Answer (score 2):

В вашем примере перед союзом ***и***  лучше поставить тире. Т.к. часть после союза заключает в себе результат, следствие.

Между частями сложносочиненного предложения ставится тире, если вторая часть предложения заключает в себе значение результата, следствия, резкого противопоставления (чаще перед союзом и, реже перед союзами но, а).

См.: Академический справочник.

Answer (score 0):

> ...10 лет производства газового оборудования
>   ***и*** произведен пятитысячный ШРП.

Без союза "и" звучать будет чуть лучше...

Comment: А если не убирать союз? Мне кажется, запятая не нужна...

Comment: _Alenka: А если не убирать союз?_ === А если не убирать, тогда я пас.

Comment: Без союза и получится перечисление.